# How to read the list of Virtual Machines in the VmWare Workstation 12 Library?

Tags: python, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I'm trying to find all the virtual machines installed in a machine. Generally all the VM's list is available in the library of the VmWare (side panel) in the application. 
Is there anyway i can get the list of all the available vm's irrespective of running or not, outside of the application to run in python script. 
I know I can get the running Machines using `vmrun list` command.
Kindly correct me if I am wrong or going in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences.ini file has all the detils of machines i am looking for

```
C:/Program Files/VMware/preferences.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

The VMware Workstation Virtual Machines List (Library Panel) is in the file "`inventory.vmls`":

```
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Roaming\VMware
```